# HP Photosmart 5510 multifunction printer scanner not found

Tags: hp, scanning

I can not get my Ubuntu 11.10 system to recognize the scanner in my HP Photosmart 5510 multi-funtion printer.  I have loaded the HPLIP extras from my terminal window and loaded the latest HPLIP.

I have searched the web and all forums for any mention of Photosmart 5510 Ubuntu drivers with no success.  I have Simple Scan, Skanlite, and XSane all installed.  The printer prints well, the USB works in any way I can detect.

Answer (score 3):

Install the latest HPLIP. Unplug the USB cable. Activate wireless printing on the printers touch screen and follow the instructions . Run HP-SETUP. Select "Wireless/802.11". Follow the instructions and your set to go.

For some reason if you use the USB connection and select "Universal Serial Bus (USB)" during the HP-STUP you get a Communication Error. But with Wireless every thing works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If, like for me "Wireless/802.11" does not work, choose "jetdirect/wireless" instead.